# is it possible to import file if the file name is in variable?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a something a variable defined like this:

```
file = "filename_" + getpass.getuser()
```

and I would like to import this file

```
import file
```

is this possible ?

Comment: look into using `__import__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it, some more Pythonic than others.
(It should be pointed out that dynamic importing of modules is a little uncommon, and there's *generally* a better way of doing it.)

Using `exec`:

```
module_name = "filename_{0}".format(getpass.getuser())
exec_string = "import {0}".format(module_name)
exec exec_string
```

This'll bring the module into the namespace, but is somewhat vulnerable to arbitrary code execution, and you'd need to make eval calls to actually access the module.

A better way is using `__import__` or the `importlib` module, the two are interchangable in Python 2.X.

```
module = __import__(module_name)
```

or

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

Comment: +1 for both examples and "there's generally a better way of doing it", but with the note that sometimes it's unavoidable

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) built-in function.

You also might be interested in the [`imp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) and [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) modules.